# Mapping results of DB query to JSON object

Tags: java, spring-boot

Entity class is as follows:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
public class Address implements Serializable {
   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "line1")
    private String line1;

    @Column(name = "line2")
    private String line2;
}
```

Repository Class

```
@Repository
public interface AddressRepo extends JpaRepository<SourceAddress, int>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<SourceAddress> {

    @Query(value = "select * from Address ", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Address> getAdressResults();
}
```

DTO is as follows

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class AddressDto implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String line1;
    private Strinline2;
}
```

If I invoke getAddressResults() from Address repository, how can I map it to DTO, and create a JSON object?

Comment: You're asking two different things. 1) how to map to the DTO, and 2) how to create a JSON object. Please focus on one thing per question. Also, it is good to know that creating JSON from objects is practically built-in into Spring Boot, but the right solution depends on **where** you need to serialize to JSON, so you need to be specific about what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could achieve this DTO to JSON response conversion in a Spring boot REST API project by using the model mapper library.

This will reduce the boiler plate code that we need to write manually otherwise.

Please check the below sample dummy code for your need.

First you need to add the modelMapper dependency in your project pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Then You need to configure ModelMapper class as a Spring Bean to inject for your REST Controller.

```
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootApp {

@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    return new ModelMapper();
}
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootApp.class, args);
    }

}
```

According to your given example, you could directly write your conversion in the controller layer while getting the Repository layer address results.

Ideally, it could be done in a separate Service Layer as well.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/addresses")
public class AddressController {

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    private AddressRepo addressRepo ;

    @Autowired
    public AddressController(AddressRepo AddressRepo ) {
        super();
        this.addressRepo = addressRepo ;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public  List<Address> getAllAddress() {

       // Address Entity to DTO conversion
        return addressRepo.getAdressResults().stream().map(address-> modelMapper.map(address, AddressDto.class))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Now, This will return you the expected JSON response object for your API call.

Moreover, you could also wrap your Address List response in a `ResponseEntity<List<Address>>` and return it as well.